# How to check if a user is authenticated with my java backend to upload a file to a nodejs media server?

Tags: java, node.js, authentication, file-upload

I have a java EE backend and users use a token based authentication to communicate to the server. Now I developed a media server using NodeJs to let users upload their media into the mentioned server to prevent the main server from media upload overheads. 
What is the best way to be sure that the user who wants to upload is an authenticated user? Should I send its token to the media server and check it with java backend before starting to upload? Or Should I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

If the media server is public you certainly need to have to the client send the token along.
Then you have to verify the token is valid. Depending on how you create and verify a token you have to talk to the backend or do some verification only inside the media server itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to *try it*. If he's authenticated, it will succeed. If not, not.